# How do I use "flex-flow: column wrap"?

Tags: css, flexbox

## Short version

When using `flex-flow: column wrap` and `display: inline-flex`, it doesn't shrinkwrap like `inline-block`:

[image]

```js
(function() {
  var ascending = true;
  setInterval(function() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('flex');
    if (ascending) {
      var child = document.createElement('p');
      child.innerHTML = "foo";
      parent.appendChild(child);
    } else {
      parent.removeChild(parent.children[0]);
    }
    if (parent.children.length <= 1) ascending = true;
    if (parent.children.length >= 40) ascending = false;
  }, 20);
})();
(function() {
  var ascending = true;
  setInterval(function() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('failex');
    if (ascending) {
      var child = document.createElement('p');
      child.innerHTML = "foo";
      parent.appendChild(child);
    } else {
      parent.removeChild(parent.children[0]);
    }
    if (parent.children.length <= 1) ascending = true;
    if (parent.children.length >= 40) ascending = false;
  }, 20);
})();
```

```css
#flexdesc {position: absolute; top: 25px;}
#flex {
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  transform: matrix(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#flex > p {
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  transform: matrix(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
}
#failexdesc {position: absolute; top: 275px;}
#failex {
  top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  max-height: 200px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

#failex > p {
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="flexdesc">What I expect it to do</div>
  <div id="flex">
    <p>foo</p>
    
    <!-- add extra "<p>foo</p>" here. -->
  </div>
  <div id="failexdesc">What it does</div>
  <div id="failex">
    <p>foo</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the size of each flex container changes (or doesn't change!)

I want this behavior because I want to place these element side by side for a horizontally scrolling website.

**Why doesn't it shrinkwrap? How do I make it shrinkwrap?**

---

## Original question

`flex-flow: row wrap` is simple enough to understand. If nothing is "flexing", it acts similar to inline elements; It flows to the right until it can't do so anymore, at which point it makes a new row.

`flex-flow: column wrap` with `display: flex` is similar. It flows down, until it can't flow down anymore (`max-width`?), and then starts a new column. Of course, since the parent is  `display: flex`, it's a block-level element, so that column will be halfway over due to the fact that `align-content` defaults to `stretch`. I could easily change that to `flex-start` to make the new column adjacent to the previous.

...but the container is still too wide. It's still a block, and fills the width of it's parent.

**I need the flexbox to shrink-to-fit its columns.** Why? I'm trying to use flexbox in a horizontally scrolling website. Granted, I could just let the children overflow, but that overflowing tends to... break things.
So I figured I needed `flex-flow: column wrap` with `display: inline-flex`. I was hoping for a "top to bottom, left to right" effect, where the parent has no empty space.

...and then [**this**](http://jsbin.com/EGEMUfo/6) happened. In chrome, the parent width is equal to the sum of the widths of the children, but otherwise, wrapping is normal. In firefox, the parent is full width, and just grows taller to accomodate the elements (I don't think firefox supports wrapping). In IE11, the width is correct, but the children just overflow down (even out of the body).

I'm so confused.

What am I doing wrong here? I understand that flexbox is a more recent feature, but I can't tell how much of this is my fault vs the browser.

By they way, I'm testing this in chrome. A chrome-only solution is fine by me. (But an elegant catch-all solution is always nice!)

---

Here's [the code for the demo I linked to](http://jsbin.com/EGEMUfo/6), in case jsbin is down:

```js
var ascending = true;
   setInterval(function() {
     var parent = document.getElementById('flex');
     if (ascending) {
       var child = document.createElement('p');
       child.innerHTML = "f";
       parent.appendChild(child);
     } else {
       parent.removeChild(parent.children[0]);
     }
     if (parent.children.length <= 1) ascending = true;
     if (parent.children.length >= 30) ascending = false;
   }, 200);
```

```css
#flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 10px;
}
body {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: 1px dashed black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="flex">
    <p>f</p>
    <!-- add extra "<p>foo</p>" here. -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE10 supports prefixed properties from an [older specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).  The problem appears to stem from using inline-flex with the column direction (if you switch to row orientation, it shrinks to fit as you expect).  Flexbox is a bit complicated, so you'll need to provide more markup to get a good solution for this.

Comment: This is probably the best resource I have used to gain a better understanding of Flexbox. It probably has an answer for you. http://flexbox.io/

Comment: This may provide an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39095473/3597276

Comment: thanks so match  i suffered  to arrive this shape

Answer (score 15):

This was a bug indeed. Here the links to tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247963
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397

As OP wanted:

> I need the flexbox to shrink-to-fit its columns. Why? I'm trying to use flexbox in a horizontally scrolling website. Granted, I could just let the children overflow, but that overflowing tends to... break things. So I figured I needed flex-flow: column wrap with display: inline-flex. I was hoping for a "top to bottom, left to right" effect, where the parent has no empty space.

We can simply achieve it with `flex-flow: column wrap;`, `align-content: flex-start;` and a fixed height wrapper together.

http://output.jsbin.com/qixuxiduxe/1

```
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  align-self: flex-start
}

body {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsbin.com/qixuxiduxe/1/edit?html,css,js,console

Comment: It looks like [the bug still exists](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397). The container still doesn't have the proper width, whether using `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`. The width of a `display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; align-content: flex-start;` remains fixed. I'm on chrome version 54.0.2840.59 (latest stable). Perhaps you are on a newer build where it is fixed?

Comment: You are right. I'm in chrome 53. I think both bug are little different.

Comment: Can this be done without a fixed height and instead a fixed number of columns before wrapping? Using flex-basis: 100% / number leaves the container stretched as if all were on top of each other without wrapping.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't know the height of each item or how many items you will have, a more flexible solution is this:

```
.parent {
  column-count: 4
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

You may also need to adjust `margin-top` of `.child:first-child` if they don't align to the top.

Comment: Don't copy/paste the same answer all over, post at one place and then vote to close on the other ... [Is it ok to copy/paste myself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317609/is-it-ok-to-copy-paste-myself)

Comment: Furthermore, if you do think you know a solution that will provide the flow asked for, provide a working code snippet instead of only a CSS fragment.

Comment: I'll try to take your rebukes and downvotes to heart. In my defense, I had just spent too much time looking at SO pages about flex, when what I needed was column-count, and I was trying to help others to have a better experience.

Comment: @Marcus For what it’s worth, this answer saved me a lot of trouble going down the wrong road for the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: This solution dramatically decreased the code footprint of what would have been a very complex masonry layout... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I had a

```css
div {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

But child items were not wrapping, it was only one column.
The solution was giving the div `max-height` property
then items wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'column-wrap' is not fully supported by Firefox. As you said, you'll need this in Chrome, in that case you can see what Chris Coyier did: add webkit prefix --> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It's supported now. I addeded code snippet in question and it runs nicely in firefox developer edition

Answer (score -2):

strong text

```html
<div  style="height: 250px; width: 100%; outline: 1px dashed black; position: relative; ">
  <div id="flex" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; max-height: 100%; overflow: auto; align-content: flex-end; background: red;">
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">START</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">1</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">2</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">3</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">4</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">5</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">6</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">7</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">8</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">9</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">10</p>
 
        <p style="margin: 0; outline: 1px solid black; width: 52px; height: 52px;">END</p>  
  </div>
```

The outer  sets the container's height to 250px and its width to 100% of its parent. It applies an outline with a dashed black border to visualize its boundary. It's positioned relative to its parent.

Inside the outer , there's another  with the id flex. This inner  serves as a flex container with the following styles:

display: flex;: Sets it as a flex container.
flex-wrap: wrap;: Specifies that flex items should wrap onto multiple lines if needed.
flex-direction: column;: Sets the main axis to be vertical, stacking the items from top to bottom.
justify-content: flex-start;: Aligns flex items to the start of the main axis (top in this case).
position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;: Positions the flex container at the bottom-left corner of its closest positioned ancestor.
max-height: 100%;: Sets the maximum height of the flex container to 100% of its containing block.
overflow: auto;: Enables scrollbars when the content overflows the container's dimensions.
align-content: flex-end;: Aligns the content at the end of the container in the cross-axis (to the right in this case).
background: red;: Sets a red background color for visualization.
Inside the flex container, there are several

elements, each with a width and height of 52px, and an outline of 1px solid black. These

elements represent the flex items with content ranging from "START" to "END".

This setup creates a flexbox layout where items are stacked vertically from the bottom to the top, and the content overflows the container vertically if it exceeds the specified height. The overflow: auto; property ensures that scrollbars appear when necessary. Adjustments can be made to the dimensions and positioning to fit specific layout requirements.

Comment: This would be much more useful if it explained what it does and how it solves the problem. A lump of code with no explanations is not very useful. Other answers suggest it was a bug in (a version of) the web browser.