# Flexbox: wrong width calculation when flex-direction: column, flex-wrap: wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I ran into a problem when using flexbox.

I'm using a container with `flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap`, so my inner items can actually be placed in multiple columns.

The problem is that the browser still calculates the container's width as **a  sum of inner items' widths**!

My container block should have a smaller width (based on content size), but it is actually huge.

Anyway, it's also very unnatural to calculate container's width this way when using columns, not rows.

Take a look at the green block in my code. It has a huge with, but it isn't supposed to have so. Also, it gets smaller as you remove an item from the container.

What I expect is to have the container with small width, so it wouldn't take more than a half of the available space.

Checked this on the latest Safari and Chrome on the latest OS X.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcsd8emp/)**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #aa0000;
  height: 100px;
}
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.g1 {
  background: #00aa00;
}
.g2 {
  background: #0000aa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group g1">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group g2">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be yet another bug in the [Flexible Box Layout Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) involving `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Browsers seem to be all over the place on this issue.

In this particular case, as stated in a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247963):

> It seems to me that the width is calculated as if the inside elements were laid out horizontally (`flex-direction: row`) instead of vertically.

In other cases, the opposite occurs:

- *[When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)*

In both cases, there are currently no flex methods to resolve the problem.

For this particular question, one developer offers a CSS workaround, but I'm not sure it works in all browsers. I wouldn't recommend it unless you're truly desperate:

> In some instances, you may be able to workaround this issue by using
>   vertical writing mode.
>
> That is, instead of using `flex-direction: column;`, use
>   `flex-direction: row; writing-mode: vertical-lr;`. Remember to reset
>   to `writing-mode: initial;` in the children of the flexbox.
>
> <sub>*https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397*</sub>

Bug reports:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247963
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507397
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995020
- https://codereview.chromium.org/289903007
- https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=178925

Answer (score 0):

You have no pre determined width so it'd register it as a 50% width field. Generally you'd set a width in group g1 and then flex: 1; in group g2

Answer (score 0):

well. the two groups have the width of `50%` ( half) of their parent `.container` which by default has `width:100%` of the body . so if you want your columns to be smaller either make the `.container` smaller , either make one group smaller, for example `.g1` `width :30%`

see both examples below :

1. .g1 smaller

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #aa0000;
  height: 100px;
  
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;

}

.g1 {
  background: #00aa00;
    width:30%;
}

.g2 {
  background: #0000aa;
  /*flex:1; could also use this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="group g1">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group g2">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. container smaller

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #aa0000;
  height: 100px;
  width:50%;
  
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;

}

.g1 {
  background: #00aa00;

}

.g2 {
  background: #0000aa;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="group g1">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group g2">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone encountering this niche problem post 2023, it seems that adding `width: fit-content;` to the container solves this issue.

[Amended JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10p2egzq/)