# Div heights not working using Flexbox in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, sass, flexbox

Good evening everyone,

I'm having trouble with Flexbox in the safari browser displaying attributes correctly in accordance with my CSS. Disclaimer I'm using SASS to compile my CSS but I don't think that's the issue.

Here is my problem: Safari is showing the yellow box, denoting the 'active' link, around the text and not expanding to the boundaries of the `div`

[image: Safari Styles]

As you can see the yellow background does not sit flush with the purple nav bar when viewed in Safari. I didn't know this until I deployed my app to Heroku and looked at the website on my iPhone 6 because the device toolbar in Chrome lied to me:

[image: Android Styles]

I've tried using prefixes and changing the way I declare the `flex` property from `flex: 1` to `flex: 1 1 auto` which is better accepted by Safari I've read.  **Interestingly** I was able to 'close the gap' by increasing the padding (top and bottom) of the yellow box which has a class name of `.active`.

Here is my `nav.scss` file:

```
#navigation{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #9b59b6;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden; /* hide excess div height from padding */

    div {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
        }
    /* receive .active if the link is clicked */
        .active{
          background: yellow;
          padding: 7% 0; /* ensure padding always extends beyond border of #navigation */
        }

        a {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
          height: 100%; /* height to fill the div so text doesn't have to be clicked exclusively */
          font-size: 4vh;
          margin: 0 auto;
          font-family: 'Athiti', serif;
          color: black;
          text-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          text-decoration: none;}
```

The comments explain what is going on here, and I should be happy I solved my issue but I would like to learn from the wise sages on StackOverflow what the "right" way of solving this problem is. I appreciate you taking the time to look at this and will be lurking in the comments.

Cheers!

Comment: It would be helpful if we could reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But before you invest a lot of time and effort into this question, check these posts: [**one**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276), [**two**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276) and [**three**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39617628/3597276).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael_B I have some reading to do.