# giving same widths on stacked flex elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to position elements, an `img` and `div`, side by side which then stack on top of each other when the browser width becomes smaller to make it responsive.

I have managed to do this to a degree however I am unable to get the 2 elements to be the same widths when they are stacked on top of each other.

Also I am having trouble vertically aligning the text in the div to be in the middle instead of the top.

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/31c5vLn6/

Code:

```
.upperSection{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.upperBox{
    background-color:white;
    text-align: center;
    verticle-align:middle;
}
.description{
    background-color: white;
}


<div class="upperSection">
        <img src="https://picturethismaths.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/fig6bigforblog.png?w=419&h=364">
        <div class="upperBox">
            <div class="description">
                <span class="header"><br>Header</span>
                <br><br>
                <span class="text">Text Goes here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use a media query and switch the flex-direction to column

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your reply, this works however this moves the entire 'upperSection' div to the right and off center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.upperSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.upperBox {
  display: flex;                     /* 1 */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  
}
.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;                            /* 2 */
  background-color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .upperSection { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  .upperBox { width: 100%; }          /* 3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="upperSection">
  <img src="https://picturethismaths.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/fig6bigforblog.png?w=419&h=364">
  <div class="upperBox">
    <div class="description">
      <span class="header">Header</span>
      <span class="text">Text Goes here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31c5vLn6/3/)

Notes:

1. By making this element a flex container, you're applying `align-items: stretch` to the child. This gives `.description` the height of the container, and `justify-content` then has space to work.
2. Similar to #1, this gives the element full width, giving `text-align: center` space to work.
3. Since the parent is a row-direction flex container, `flex: 1` would work here, as well.

Comment: Is it safe to use `flex-direction: column;` nowadays?

Comment: @RicardoRuiz, I've haven't seen any problems with `flex-direction: column` with default settings. A container with `column wrap`, however, that's another story. You'll find lots of bugs there.

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Michael_B  Damn really? not so long ago I changed all the `flex-direction` values in a project thinking it was not safe `:(`, but I think I used wrap as well so...  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @RicardoRuiz, a few reasons why I don't think `column wrap` is ready for prime time. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39095473/3597276), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39617628/3597276) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276).

Comment: @Michael_B Excellent answers and resources, thanks again Michael, you're greatly contributing to get away from the floats era in this kind of layout.

Answer (score -2):

Don't you think the **vertical-align: ** should be **center**.

Comment: **center** is not a valid value for [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).