# flex-wrap not working in nested flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I expected the blue and red box to wrap when the screen width is small in this example, because the cyan box is set to flex-wrap.

However, that's not happening. Why is this not working?

Here is the code:

```css
.foo,
.foo1,
.foo3 {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ffea61;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #999;
  display: flex;
}

.foo1 {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.foo2 {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.foo3 {
  background: cyan;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bar1,
.bar2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.bar2 {
  background: red;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: orange;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="foo1"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="foo2">
      <div class="foo3">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo1"></div>
</div>
```

Please see the details in the following link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxExjL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug with a `column wrap` flex container. The cyan box is refusing to shrink, which prevents the red box from wrapping.

You could set a width to the second column or `.foo2` or `.foo3`, and that will force the items to wrap. But that's probably not what you want.

One workaround is to not use `column wrap` in this case. Stick to `row nowrap`:

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  background: orange;
  height: 150px;
}

.foo,
.foo1,
.foo3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ffea61;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #999;
}

.foo {
  flex: 1;
}

.foo1 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: green;
}

.foo2 {
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.foo3 {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: cyan;
}

.bar1,
.bar2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
}

.bar2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="foo1"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="foo2">
      <div class="foo3">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo1"></div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpwQPJ?editors=1100)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works. I accepted this as the correct answer. My actual problem is more complicated than this and require me to use flex-dir: column. So the flex-dir:row solution wouldn't work in my case. But this is a good answer! Thanks!

Comment: @louis.luo, just an FYI, in case you're not already aware: There are several flexbox problems that are unique to `column wrap`. I personally don't think `column wrap` is ready for prime time. That's one reason I normally stick to `row`-based layouts.

Comment: For more details see: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095473/flexbox-wrong-width-calculation-when-flex-direction-column-flex-wrap-wrap), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617628/height-of-flex-container-not-working-properly-in-safari) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480760/is-it-possible-for-the-items-in-a-flexbox-container-that-wraps-in-rows-to-align).