# Why does flex container have such height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```html
 <flex1 style="width: 400px; padding: 5px; background-color: #333; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <item style="background-color: #999;">
        <flex2 style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 7px;">
            <one style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px; flex-basis: 50%; margin-right:3px;">One</one>
            <two style="background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px;">Two</two>
        </flex2>
    </item>
</flex1>
```

[I expect that flex1 will wrap around flex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4iHK.png)

Seems like flex2 has an invisible wrap. But if you remove `flex: wrap` from flex1 then that wrap will disappear. Really strange behaviour that is implemented in all browsers.

Comment: seems another bug due to nesting

Comment: Try my code, posted below.

Comment: In short, when using a single-line flex container, you should use `nowrap`. [This answer could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890613/remove-space-gaps-between-multiple-lines-of-flex-items-when-they-wrap#answer-40890703)

Comment: Lots of browsers bugs with flex `column wrap`. See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39095473/3597276), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39617628/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42451219/3597276).