# Flex-wrap with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the `div` elements to **distribute horizontally** when the height of the `.container` meets the bottom of the `.resize` wrapper.

When I drag the window to shrink the height of the `.container`, I want to be to also shrink the `.resize` wrapper when the bottom of the `.container` meets the bottom of the `.resize` wrapper so that the elements `flex-wrap` and distribute horizontally in proportion to the dynamic height of the `.container`.

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.resize {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.resize > div {
  border: 2px solid #555;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="resize">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think flexbox can do this.

What you want is possible in row direction. (Shrink the window horizontally in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dtsp7eyn/))

But it doesn't work in column direction. (Shrink the window vertically in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dtsp7eyn/1/)).

This may be another deficiency with flexbox in `column wrap` mode. Here are several others:

- [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)
- [Flexbox: wrong width calculation when flex-direction: column, flex-wrap: wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39095473/3597276)
- [Height of flex container not working properly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39617628/3597276)
- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)
- [flex-wrap not working in nested flex container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42451219/3597276)