# Grid template rows no longer functioning as expected with Chrome 83

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, css-grid

In previous versions of Chrome, you could define `grid-template-rows` such that certain rows were fixed height and others would expand like the flex model. This no longer appears to be the case and I have provided a fiddle as an example.

The `header` and `footer` div have their height set to 100px, and their template-row value set to `auto`. The `main` div has no height defined and its template-row value is set to `1fr`. The expected behavior is that the `main` div should fill the remaining height of 800px, but its client height is zero.

My question, with respect to the fiddle, why is the `main` div not expanding to fill the remaining height of the `grid` div?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 1000px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  flex: 1;
  grid-template-areas: 
     "header" 
      "main"
     "footer";
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqxLd6tm/2/

Comment: not related to the grid but flexbox, the flex:1 is not doing its job .. adding height: 0; to the grid fixes the issue (don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like yet another bug with `flex-direction: column` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172784/3597276)) and/or nested flex containers ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/3597276)).

In your code, `flex: 1` is apparently being ignored. Or maybe it's being factored into the layout after other box sizes have been computed, so it's having no effect.

In any case, you can resolve the problem by using a `row` instead of a `column` direction container.

Since a container with `flex-direction: row` automatically sets `align-self: stretch` to the children, you no longer need `flex: 1` for the height. But you still need it for the width.

In short, you only need to make one change to your code: remove `flex-direction: column`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 1000px;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  flex: 1;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "main"
    "footer";
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="main"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```