# Height of flex container changing unexpectedly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a list of elements and spacing them evenly with 4 per row using a flex box with direction row. I also need a surrounding container with flex direction column to have more elements below this. The problem is that I am seeing the height of the flex box inside change sometimes when I use the flex-basis property.

I have tried 4 different options. Here are their descriptions and whether they behave correctly or not:

- Flex Basis with 2 options (behaves incorrectly)
- Flex Basis with 3 options (behaves incorrectly)
- Flex Basis with 4 options (behaves correctly)
- No flex basis and only a min-width (behaves correctly)

Here is the CSS of my containing divs in my flexbox (4 per row). Essentially, `.box2` works correctly whereas `.box1` behaves unexpectedly.
Also here is a codepen to illustrate the problem:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVWMqb

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
}

.box2 {
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flex basis with 2 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Flex basis with 3 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 3</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Flex basis with 4 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 3</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 4</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Flex basis with 5 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 3</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 4</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 5</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Without flex basis</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box2'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box2'>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
```

I would expect there to be no space below the list of options, however, there is in certain cases as shown in the codepen. I do not expect the text to take up any more space than it's line height, so I am confused where the extra space is coming from in some situations but not others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've run into yet another bug with wrapping columns in flexbox.

If you remove `flex-wrap: wrap` from `.container`, the layout works as you expect. It doesn't appear you need this rule anyway.

Also note that the bug is active in Chrome and Firefox. But your original code works fine in Edge.

Flex layout with `column wrap` has many bugs. It's possibly the most bug-ridden area in flexbox today. Here are two more examples:

- [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)
- [Flexbox: wrong width calculation when flex-direction: column, flex-wrap: wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39095473/3597276)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
}

.box2 {
  min-width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flex basis with 2 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Flex basis with 3 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 3</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Flex basis with 4 options</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box1'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 2</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 3</div>
    <div class='box1'>Option 4</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Without flex basis</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='boxes'>
    <div class='box2'>Option 1</div>
    <div class='box2'>Option 2</div>
  </div>
  text below
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a thought to this topic or bug as suggested:

1. Considering that this phenomenon occurs only in flexboxes with the flex-wrap property and CSS width property behaves differently for flexboxes.
2. I understand the basic applicable concept of flexboxes that they are designed to behave based on the resizing of the containers but I am not sure what concept is used by the language developers so that flexboxes can change their width adapt the available space.

I believe that flexboxes do not change their dimension based on the content enclosed within them since css width property do not behave properly on element with flex property. Rather flexboxes are filled with some kind of an imaginary pixelated content which gets replaced by the elements later. When flex-wrap property is applied, the imaginary content is getting wrapped down based on the entered px.

It can be considered as bug since the phenomenon is only occurring in chrome and firefox but isn't is also chromium based?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).